# Why is 2018-01 is changed in to 2017 in Scala+Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
val str = "2018-01"
var df = Seq((10,"2018-01-22")).toDF("sno","date")

df.show
df.createOrReplaceTempView("dd")

var ddf = spark.sql("select sno,date," + str.toString + " as new from dd")
ddf.show
```

The output is:

```
str: String = 2018-01 
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [sno: int, date: string] 
+---+----------+ 
|sno|      date| 
+---+----------+ 
| 10|2018-01-22|
 +---+----------+ 

ddf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [sno: int, date: string ... 1 more field] 
+---+----------+----+ 
|sno| date     | new| 
+---+----------+----+ 
| 10|2018-01-22|2017| 
+---+----------+----+
```

Why is `str.toString` changed into "2017" instead of "2018-01"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not the `str.toString` changing the value, but the select statement, which is interpreting 2018-01 as arithmetic operation to give 2017 (which is correct and expected behaviour).
If you wish to preserve the value of str then surround str.toString by quotes in select statement. Like this:

```
var ddf = spark.sql("select sno,date,'"+str.toString+"' as new from dd")
```

Answer (score 0):

"2018-01" is interpreted as `2018 - 1` (subtraction) which equals 2017. To avoid this add single quotes around the string:

```
spark.sql("select sno,date,'" + str + "' as new from dd")
```

There is no need to add `toString` since it already is a string.This will give you the expected output:

```
+---+----------+-------+
|sno|      date|    new|
+---+----------+-------+
| 10|2018-01-22|2018-01|
+---+----------+-------+
```